# JFreeChart CandlestickChart how to change time interval?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm creating an application that draws Candlestick Charts from a data in a text file. I also want the user to be able to choose different time intervals for the data. Let's say my starting data are 1s ticks in the following format:

CYBATON,0,20150101,080001,1.18,4.09,1.02,1.92

where "20150101" is a date and "080001" is a precise hour. Then I create OHLCItems with the following code responsible for setting OHLCItem's RegularTimePeriod:

```
    String stringDate ="20150101" + "080001";
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Date date=null;
            try {
                date = format.parse(stringDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    Hour hour=new Hour(date);
    OHLCItem ohlcItem=new OHLCItem(hour, open, max, min, close);
```

Now my chart will display data in a 1s ticks. Is there an easy way to switch to different ticks? Let's say hourly or daily? Or do I have to do it with manual calculations? If it's ok, I would also like to know how to store the entire date within the OHLCItem? Including year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds.

Comment: I think you'd have to resample the data, probably in the model. Doesn't `getPeriod()` let you recover the `Date`?

Comment: Hey @trashgod. Resampling the data shouldn't be a problem if only I could get the full date from previously created OHLCItems. But afaik, when I create a new OHLCItem one of the arguments is a subclass of RegularTimePeriod, which is one of the following: Day, FixedMillisecond, Hour, Millisecond, Minute, Month, Quarter, Second, Week, Year. From what I can see, none of those classes provide the full Date, including year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds. getPeriod() returns an instance of the class I provided when creating an OHLCItem.

Comment: Depending on your resampling approach, maybe use the start, middle or end millisecond.

Comment: Hey @trashgod, thx for the idea, got it working using the miliseconds :)

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).